# How to display pdf file in aspx page using asp.net control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I need to display pdf file inside aspx page (using asp.net control) on-click of button.

I have currently executed the below code which is displaying pdf file in Web Browser.

```
string folderPath = 
    Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverFolderPath"].ToString());
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
{
    WebClient user = new WebClient();
    Byte[] fileBuffer = user.DownloadData(file);

    if (fileBuffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", fileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        sponse.BinaryWrite(fileBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use iframe for it check refrence https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20699/Embed-PDFs-into-a-Web-Page-with-a-Custom-Control

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if your folderPath is correct
its working

```
        string strDirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\UserDesktopName\Desktop\";
        WebClient User = new WebClient();
        foreach (string strFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(strDirectoryPath))
        {
            string strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFilePath);
            if (strFileExtension == ".pdf")
            {
                Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(strFilePath);
                this.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition;", "attachment;filename=" + FileBuffer);
                this.Response.WriteFile(strFilePath);
                this.Response.End();
            }
        }
```